# How to increment a variable after button press

Tags: javascript

I was wondering how I could increase a variable when a button is clicked. here is my code. Can somebody point me in the right direction? thanks.

I am thinking when the button1 is clicked it will increase team 1's score by like 10, and will decrease if it is clicked again if that is necessary.

```
var Team2;
var Team2 == 0;
var Team1;
var Team1 == 0;
document.getElementById("calc").innerHTML = Team1;



function clicked(button1)
{
var team1 = team1 + 45
}
</SCRIPT>
<p>
Players for Team 1
```

Comment: Shouldn't `team1 = team1` be **T**eam1? With a capital "T" Also I don't see anything calling `clicked()`

Comment: The same way you have called `writeText()` assuming you want the to be called when those buttons are clicked...

Comment: Try adding `onClick="readText(this.form);writeText();` to your button inputs. Also where is the `readText` function? And why are you passing `button1` into the `writeText` function but never using it? Can you display all *relevant* source code.

Comment: Well since Janet appears to be repeating everything I post I will leave her to give you a demo or solution. To be honest I think you just need to do a little research before using javascript. I wish you the best of luck.

Comment: FYI, `var Team2 == 0;` is invalid JavaScript. You might want to read a tutorial, like http://eloquentjavascript.net/ .

Comment: Just to be clear your question is out of sync with the title "radio button is clicked" those are not radio inputs.

Comment: Exactly, @MarkSchultheiss. I made an edit, but we have 1 aprove and 1 reject so far...

Comment: @GerardoFurtado  Yes, that comment was just to help instruct the OP on the question quality.

Comment: @shrafford2 Please do not deface posts. Once posted, they belong to the community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the variable part: suppose you define a variable `var value = 0`. To increase it by 10, you can write `value = value + 10`, but in JavaScript this can be shorten to:

```
value += 10
```

The same way, to decrease it, just write `value -= 10`.

To call the function, you write `onClick="someFunction()"` (not the best practice), and then you define the function:

```
function someFunction(){
  value += 10
};
```

This is the working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/6qh1yhsj/

If you want to see how to do the same thing without the `onClick="someFunction()"` part, here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/wff8mph3/

PS: I see that in your code you wrote `var team2 == 0`. In JavaScript, two equal signs make a comparison operator: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp

PS2: In JavaScript, you have to mind the scope. Once you defined the `var team1`, you can change it inside the function just by writing `team1`. But if you do as you did:

```
function someFunction(){
  var team1 = team1 + 45
};
```

This `team1` is not the same previous variable `team1` defined outside the function. It's a different variable. And, as the team1 to the right of the equal sign is not defined, this will return a NaN (Not-A-Number).

Comment: also you don't need to make a function to call another one on click event , you can simply make that 


document.getElementById("increase").addEventListener("click", increase);

Comment: Thanks, @El.oz, I just changed the fiddle.